# Compute Parabola using python

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

```
def parabola(h, k, xCoordinates):
```

h
is
the
x
coordinate
where
the
parabola
touches
the
x
axis
and
k
is
the
y
coordinate
where
the
parabola
intersects
the
y
axis
and
xCoordinates
is
a
list
of
x
coordinates
along
the
major
axis.
The
function
returns
a
list
of
y
coordinates
using
the
equation
shown
below.
There
will
be
one
y
coordinate
for
each
x
coordinate
in
the
list
of
x
coordinates.

```
y(x, h, k) = a(x − h)2, where a =k/h2
```

I know how to work in python as i already compute the area ,

```
def computeArea(y_vals, h):
    i=1
    total=y_vals[0]+y_vals[-1]
    for y in y_vals[1:-1]:
        if i%2 == 0:
            total+=2*y
        else:
            total+=4*y
        i+=1
    return total*(h/3.0)
y_values=[13, 45.3, 12, 1, 476, 0]
interval=1.2
area=computeArea(y_values, interval)
print "The area is", area
```

But the question above is hurting me because its pure mathmatics , i just want little bit help

Comment: I presume here that the 2 `2`s in your equation are exponents? So `a(x-h)` squared, and what part of `k/h` is squared? `h` only, or the whole division? My parabola math is.. rusty.

Comment: You can use the [`**` power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) here, so `something ** 2` to square `something`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in k/h square in only on h , and a(x-h) square in on (x-h)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`**` power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) to square values:

```
y = (k / h ** 2) * (x - h) ** 2
```

where `**` exponentiation has a [higher precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than multiplication or division.

So for a series of `x` coordinates, that'd be:

```
def parabola(h, k, xCoordinates):
    return [(k / h ** 2) * (x - h) ** 2 for x in xCoordinates]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Martijn Pieters is good.

If you're struggling a little with the concept I find this example to be very easy to understand (using the vertex form equation):

```
x = range(-10,10)
y = []

a = 2 # this is the positive or negative curvature
h = 0 # horizontal offset: make this term +/- to shift the curve "side to side"
k = 0 # vertical offset: make this term +/- to shift the curve "up to down"

for xi in x:
    y.append(a * (xi + h)** 2 + k)
```

You can plot it with pylab.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[math](/questions/tagged/math)